# How to remedy "System.QueryException: expecting a colon" within Batch query

Tags: soql, query, exception

I have a Batchable class for scheduling a lead reassignment process.  I recently made some edits to the query string and nod I am getting the error `System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'LAST_30_DAYS'`.

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing the error?  As far as I can tell I've written the query correctly.

Here is my code:

```
global class ChinaLeadReassignmentBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    String query;

    global ChinaLeadReassignmentBatch() {

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        query = 'SELECT ID, OwnerID, Age_in_hours__c, Status, LastActivityDate, Open_Activity_Count__c FROM Lead WHERE isConverted = FALSE AND CreatedDate = LAST_30_DAYS AND CreatedDate < YESTERDAY AND Status = \'Open\' AND (OwnerID = \'00570000001kTxHAAU\' OR OwnerID = \'00570000001jPVZAA2\') AND LastActivityDate = NULL AND Open_Activity_Count__c = 0' ;
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope) {

        List<Lead> toUpdate = new List<Lead>();

        for (Lead l : scope){
            if (l.OwnerID == '00570000001kTxHAAU') l.OwnerID = '00570000001jPVZAA2';
            if (l.OwnerID == '00570000001jPVZAA2') l.OwnerID = '00570000001kTxHAAU';
            toUpdate.add(l);
        }

        update toUpdate;

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last_30_Days is not a date literal value that you can use in a SOQL. For a complete list of date literals available in SOQL, see here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

To do last 30 days, you would need: LAST_N_DAYS:30

Comment: Thanks.  I had been referring to that exact page, and when I saw LAST_90_DAYS as an option, I guess I figured any number would work in that format.  Fixed and working now cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect.

Replace:

```
LAST_30_DAYS
```

by :

```
LAST_N_DAYS:30
```